# Identify candidates for Selenium test automation?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, test-automation, selenium

Salesforce already uses both unit tests & Selenium to automate out-of-the-box features.

Our developers are covering their code with unit tests.

In order to avoid redundancy regarding the above, how shall we identify what UI tests should also be automated with our own Selenium?

Is it only custom UI elements that we should be concerned with?

How about out-of-the-box UI elements which interact with custom apex class, triggers, JS helpers, etc?

Basically I'd like to create a checklist, that I can apply to any feature of the product to determine if it is a good candidate for UI test automation.

Like, if the feature involves x, y or z - then it's probably a good idea to automate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apex Code and Triggers should be unit tested with Apex Code. Standard components should never be tested; it would do well for you to trust that standard platform features won't break (or, if they do, they'll be fixed without your intervention).

Custom elements that rely **heavily** on JavaScript, including buttons, links, Visualforce pages and components, and Lightning components and apps, should all be Selenium tested. Lightweight, trivial JavaScript can probably be statically verified as correct without actual Selenium testing, which will probably be true for most buttons, links, and Visualforce pages.

Lightning will eventually have its own isolated-testing framework, in which case Selenium testing will no longer be necessary or even desirable. You may want to hold off on Selenium testing anything trivial, because we're going to have better tools soon.

Comment: thanks for your help. What do you mean by lightning apps? The product my team is building/testing is an app for the exchange.

Comment: @PatMeeker Everything's an "app" these days. A Lightning app is an AuraDefinitionBundle that contains an application (a stand-alone component that starts off with `aura:application`, which may or may not be the same as the app you're thinking of.

Comment: What do you mean by lightning testing framework ? Configurable automation testing for any custom app/ component , on all browsers etc ? We are currently finalizing such tool (using selenium) because we need our isv to be reliable today ... why would such vital tool become not desirable in the future ?

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy We don't know enough about what the Lightning testing framework yet, but presumably a testing framework would allow us to isolate test data from real data, something Selenium cannot do. In that case, if such a feature were released, it would be vastly superior to Selenium testing, which can cause real harm to real data. I'm not trying to dissuade people from Selenium testing in the here and now, because it's one of the best options we have, but tests should ideally not be able to affect real data.

Comment: I understand your point of view but respectfully disagree with it : selenium allows to test a full application (UI,apex, integration...) and saves a lot of time to real humans who have to click manually if they don't have such automated testing tool, so telling people to not invest in such solution, to wait for a tool we know nothing about,   is not a good idea. About data ... big tests must happen in a separate org than production org, where you can generate any dummy record needed for testing.

Comment: @NicolasVuillamy - How do you identify automaton candidates? Do you consider anything beyond whats covered by the other answer?

Comment: In my opinion, every business use case test should be automated. Basically, everything a human can test in an application. A selenium-based tool can allow that. Maybe some lightning tool can provide it too someday ... I agree with @sfdcfox answer, except on the part where he says "do not invest in testing your apps with the most commonly used open-source tool, salesforce may someday provide something" :) Apps must be reliable NOW, not someday when SFDC decices to provide some beta of some unspecified tool. In our ISV team , we use a "home made" java tool, based on selenium WebDriver.

Comment: @sfdcfox I'm curious - (3 years later) is there a Lightning specific testing framework available?

Comment: @OryZaidenvorm LWC now ships with everything you need to write Jest tests, which is the preferred method. Aura can also apparently be tested as well, but I don't see official documentation on it (but lots of blog posts on it). Client-side testing is ideal for Lightning Component testing.

Comment: @sfdcfox my understanding (after reading more about it) is that Jest is used to test LWC in isolation. Those tests cannot replace functional test automation, and especially end to end testing.

Comment: @OryZaidenvorm end to end testing is destructive. Some people think it's great, I think it's a terrible idea, especially for code that will be in production. It is usually sufficient to test all the client-side logic together, and all the server-side logic together. It's like unit testing Apex that makes callouts. You can't verify that the callouts won't fail for some reason, so you can't do end-to-end testing there, either. This is a data safety feature.

Comment: @sfdcfox with respect, I don't even know how to reply to that. You can't replace end to end tests with component testing, no matter how thorough. Checkout https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html